Why is BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint just setting 401 status instead of sending error 401?
I'm working on a spring-boot application that supports authentication using either basic or bearer token. To do this, I defined a security configuration like this:
http.oauth2ResourceServer(Customizer.withDefaults())
    .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
    .authenticationProvider(ldapProvider)  // to validate basic credentials
// other stuff that is not relevant for my issue...

In order to send a proper 401 page to the user in case of authentication failure, I defined an error controller that responds to /error.
I noticed that when the user authenticates with basic and sends a wrong password, the error controller is properly invoked, but when he authenticates with an invalid bearer token, the error controller is not invoked and the response is an empty 401.
The difference I noticed from the code is that the BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint sends an error with status 401 by invoking response.sendError(401), while the BearerAuthenticationEntryPoint just sets the status 401 without sending the error, by just invoking response.setStatus(401).
To verify that this is the cause of my problem, I adapted the BearerAuthenticationEntryPoint so that it calls response.sendError(401) instead of response.setStatus(401), and this change solved my issue.
I'm on spring-boot 3.1.11, spring-security 6.1.9 and spring 6.0.19.
So my question is whether this is a bug or not. In the latter case, what shall I change in the configuration to invoke the error controller in case of bearer token error?
